# Symfony , no mostrar un campo en un formulario Type

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, controller

Buenas , tengo un formulario en Symfony de tipo "type" que muestra una serie de atributos , pero en un caso en concreto me gustaria mostrar todo el formulario excepto un campo.

He intentado pasarle desde el controlador al constructor del buildForm en el parámetro Options un parámetro para luego recoger y hacer la acción deseada pero no me funciona.

El código que he probado es este

```
class FormativeActionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title',TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'common.title'
            ))
            ->add('officialCode',TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'common.officialCode',
                'disabledCar' => true,
            ))
            ->add('enabled',CheckboxType::class, array(
                'required' => false  ,
                'label' => 'common.enabled'
            ));
    } 

}
```

Y desde el controlador he probado esto

```
$car = new Car();

$form = $this->createForm(CarType::class, $coche, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_car_new'),
    'disabledCar' => true
]);

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba a en tu controler a pasar la información de la acción que quieres hacer en un array

```
$form = $this->createForm('BackendBundle\Form\CarType', $coche, array(
        'accion' => $accion, //mandamos la informacion para que nos enseñe o no alguna de las opciones del formulario
    ));
```

y luego acuérdate de definirlo en la configuración de tu CarType

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BackendBundle\Entity\CarAcciones',
        'accion' => 'ADMIN',
    ));
 }
```

en este caso por defecto es ADMIN

y luego puedes sacarlo para lo que necesites , por ejemplo con un if

```
if ('USER' === $options['accion']) {
//lo que tenga que pasar

 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Carlos